# Marshal.DestroyStructure not working after .net framework upgrade

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I have upgraded my solutions .net framework from 3.5 to 4.6.1 and I got an APPCRASH error while running my tool.
So I tried to debug the code and seems like when the control reaches the below code the debugging is simply getting exited without throwing any error.
Tried exception handling to catch the error but no use.

```
Marshal.DestroyStructure(p, typeof(DS_SELECTION))
```

Example

[See this example in .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K2PYXA)

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;                   
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
{
    IntPtr p = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr dsSL = IntPtr.Zero +1;
    p = (IntPtr)(((int)dsSL) + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DS_SELECTION_LIST)));
    if(IntPtr.Zero.Equals(p) == false)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        Marshal.DestroyStructure(p, typeof(DS_SELECTION));
    }       
}
internal struct DS_SELECTION
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string pwzName;      
}

internal struct DS_SELECTION_LIST
{       
    public uint cFetchedAttributes;
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete, reproducible example.

Comment: @ckuri added an example

Comment: It is a pretty dangerous method, the number of practical cases where you *really* need to release anything are very low.  Not here, that string was not allocated by unmanaged code.  Only COM interface pointers, COM variants and BSTR strings qualify.  The memory corruption caused by calling it when you shouldn't is quite hard to diagnose and can go undetected for a long time.  Until you make a change that alters the heap allocations, like changing the framework version.  A Windows update is also a good way to trigger the crash, like running that 3.5 program on XP before.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here: you try to free memory which was not allocated, so of course it keeps crashing on you. When using unsafe code you need to take great care yourself that you only work with valid pointers - not doing so is like playing Russian Roulette. So it seems like that in your actual code you also try to access invalid memory.

Comment: This is written in Finally block of my application:          

               Marshal.DestroyStructure(p, typeof(DS_SELECTION));

The above mentioned code is just an example.
And it was working fine in 3.5 .net frame work but once the framework got upgraded to 4.6.1 this got failed.

Comment: "was working fine" - not if your real code is anything like this sample. This was "working fine" in the sense of "somehow didn't cause the application to fall over", not "doing something correctly". It "worked" on 3.5 due to *luck*, not due to correct usage. As others are trying to tell you above.

Comment: Here it is mentioned like the api is obsolete. I guess may be because of that it is getting failed.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.destroystructure?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @Aathira No, `DestroyStructure(IntPtr, Type)` is obsolete because one should use `DestroyStructure<T>(IntPtr)` instead. Hasn't to do anything with it failing or not.

Comment: @ckuri In my real application the value of p is not empty. In  your previous comment you have mentioned like  "you try to free memory which was not allocated," is not true. There is actually a value for p. Here in the above example I have written "IntPtr dsSL = IntPtr.Zero +1;" because I was not able to assign integer to dsSL that is why I have incremented 1.